# Google realtime notification when trial period ends

Tags: android, google-play-console, google-play-developer-api, google-realtime-api

Does Google send a notification when a trial period ends and they automatically initiates billing against the credit card of the user?

> https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/realtime_developer_notifications
>   http://www.androiddocs.com/google/play/billing/billing_subscriptions.html

Related to this, I only see:

> When the trial period ends, Google Play automatically initiates
>   billing against the credit card that the user provided during the
>   initial purchase, at the amount set for the full subscription, and
>   continuing at the subscription interval.

I am currently handling different types of notifications (depending on the notificationType field) but I don't know if it's possible to track trial periods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't receive any answer from Google support.

However, after deployed a webhook and receive notifications from Google, I confirmed they send an event with notificationType = SUBSCRIPTION_RENEWED when the trial period ends and the user's card is charged.